# How do I delete a string from an array?

Tags: vb.net

In my code I have an add button that adds a word to an array up to 10 times. How would I be able to make a delete button to be able to type in a word that is in the current label and delete that word from the label as well as the array.

NOTE: In order to add to the Label, you also have to type a word in the TextBox, then hit the add button.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim i, j As Integer

Dim s(9) As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'working add button

    Label1.Text = Nothing

    s(j) = TextBox1.Text

    For i = 0 To 9

        Label1.Text &= s(i) & " "
    Next

    j += 1

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    'attempt at a delete button

    s(j) = TextBox1.Text

    For i = 0 To 9

        If deleteWord = s(j) Then

            deleteWord = Nothing

            ReDim Preserve s(s.Length - 1)

            Label1.Text &= s(i) & " "

        End If

    Next

    j += 1

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Have you tried to Google this at all? Prime example - one of the very first hits; https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/77ed73c3-fb56-414a-bacf-0cdcd41afff4/remove-element-from-an-array-of-string?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: It's not clear what you think this code should do. However, if you want to be able to add and delete items from an array, you should probably use a `List(Of String)` instead of an array. [Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are designed to allow items to be added and deleted while arrays are not.

Comment: @Blackwood MY teahcer wants to have a TextBox where u type in a word then hit add and it adds it to a label. Then you can type in a word in the label and you can delete the typed word by hitting the delete button.

Comment: Then why does your question ask about add to and deleting from an array?

Comment: @Blackwood She said that the strings would go into an array. Therefore you add or delete strings to the array...

Comment: You should ask your teacher whether it makes sense to use an array in this case, given that they are not resizeable.  You could use `Redim Preserve` or `Array.Resize` to add an item, which will actually create a new array of a new size and copy the elements from the old one.  That's rather inefficient though, and you'd need extra work to fill holes if you want to remove an element somewhere in the middle. This is not something that any sane developer would do in the real world, but often learning exercises ignore that. You should check whether you MUST use an array.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I know for a fact I am supposed to. She mentioned something called 'bubble swap' do you know what she is talking about?

Comment: In that case, removing an element would be a case of first setting that element to `Nothing` and then shifting all other elements down one position and finally "resizing" the array as I mentioned before but reducing the size rather than increasing. As I said, it would be insane to do that in a real application but the idea is to give you a feel for how array elements can be manipulated, so there is some value.

Comment: @jmcilhinney So if I had my words in a label how would I approach this? What would the code be to specifically delete a word in the Label when there are 9 other words lined up?

Comment: The `Label` is basically irrelevant.  You do everything with the array and then you simply combine all of what's in the array into a single `String` and display it.  You never try to add anything to or remove anything from the `Label` itself.  So, adding a value means adding an element to the array and then displaying the contents of the array, while removing a value means removing an element from the array and then displaying the contents of the array.  You just need one method to display the contents of the array and then call that any time you have made a change to the array.

Comment: Just so you know, I'm not going to be providing code.  This is homework so it's for you to write the code.  I'll help you fix issues with your code along the way but I expect you to write it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ik, gotta get to work. :)

Comment: If you're going to post new code then you'll have to edit your question.  More than a line of code becomes basically unreadable if posted in a comment.  Like I said though, there's no such thing as deleting from the `Label`.  You're removing elements from the array.  After any change to the array, you simply concatenate all the elements and display the result in the `Label`, which means setting the `Text`, which means replacing whatever was displayed previously.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Added the new code. I don't have a clue why it isn't deleting. I am a beginner please no hate.

Comment: You've ignored a very significant portion of what I said. I said to make all your changes to the array first, then combine the elements of the array into a single `String`, then display that `String` in the `Label`. You only need to change the `Text` of the `Label` once each time the user adds or removes an item. It should be the last thing you do each time. As I said, you should write a method that displays the contents of an array in the `Label` and then call that method each time.  You should write that method first, before even trying to add or remove.

Comment: In order to add an item, these are the steps you should use: 1) Resize the array, either with `ReDim Preserve` or `Array.Resize` to increase the size by one. 2) Set the last element of the array to the new value. 3) Call the aforementioned method to display the array in the `Label`.

Comment: In order to implement removing an item, you must first make an important choice: if the same value appears more than once, will you remove just the first occurrence or all of them?

Comment: Or use a `List(Of T)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It just removes 1.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to solve your problem is to use a `List(Of T)`, because then you'd only have to do either:

```
MyList.Remove(deleteWord)
```

or:

```
MyList.RemoveAt(<index>)
```

---

But if you really want to use an array, you can get use of this extension method that I've created.

First, add a new module by going to `Add New Item` or just press `CTRL + Shift + A`. Select `Module` and name it `Extensions`.

Then copy this extension method into your module:

```
Public Module Extensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub RemoveAt(Of T)(ByRef InputArray As T(), ByVal Index As Integer)
        Array.Copy(InputArray, Index + 1, InputArray, Index, (InputArray.Length - 1) - Index)
        Array.Resize(InputArray, InputArray.Length - 1)
    End Sub
End Module
```

The extension method works like this: It copies a sub-part of itself (everything after the specified index) and replaces the item you want to remove with it. Technically it's moving every item after the specified index one step to the left. `{0, 1, 2, 3} -> {0, 2, 3, <unused>}`

Then the array is resized to remove the last, unused index.

When this is done, you can just use the extension method like this in your loop:

```
If deleteWord = s(i) Then
    s.RemoveAt(i) 'Removes the specified item.
End If
```

Or even simpler, without a loop:

```
Dim Index As Integer = Array.IndexOf(s, deleteWord)
If Index > -1 Then
    s.RemoveAt(Index)
End If
```